# Top 10 records with sum of remaining records in others in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have one table which consists of 4 Columns - (id int, location varchar (max), [date] datetime, Total_Sales Money) which consist of 20 records in output I want 11 rows in which top 10 rows as it is and 11th row should be sum of remaining rows i.e. from 11 to 20 in Other_Location. Please help me to get the query.

I want 11 rows in which top 10 rows as it is and 11th row should be sum of remaining rows

Comment: How do you define the "top 10 rows"?  By date?  By amount?

Answer (score 1):

You can select top 10 rows and 1 row sum with `union`

May be code:

```
SELECT id, location, date, total_sales FROM table limit 10 // where etc..
UNION
SELECT 0 as id, '' as location, 0 as date, sum(total_sales) as total_sales FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012, using `ROW_NUMBER()` window function, you can achive this. Create `ROW_NUMBER()` to set `RowNum` for each row and based on the result, using `UNION ALL` it will return the result:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT id, location, [date], Total_Sales,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RowNum
    FROM TableName
)

SELECT CAST(id AS VARCHAR(30)) AS Id,
       location, 
       CAST([date] AS VARCHAR(30)) AS [date], 
       CAST(Total_Sales AS VARCHAR(30)) AS Total_Sales 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 10
UNION 
SELECT '11-20 ids' AS id, 
       '11-20 AS locations' as location, 
       '11-20 dates' AS [date], 
       SUM(Total_Sales) AS Total_Sales 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 11 AND 20
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=df3f1c303473b87b7806731023bff6d6)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation.  That way, you can do this with one `group by`:

```
select (case when seqnum <= 10 then id end) as id,
       max(case when seqnum <= 10 then location else 'All else' end) as location,
       max(case when seqnum <= 10 then datetime end) as datetime,
       sum(amount)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by amount desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by (case when seqnum <= 10 then id end);
```